# git pull not updating a branch with merged branches

Tags: git, github

I am having a problem with git. So,there was one new branch(a) that was committed for review. While it was in review, another branch was created (b). Branch a was merged into the main branch dev from which a and b were created.

Now in branch b, there are some code that is present in branch a that can be used. I pulled dev branch and I did get the merged code.But when I check out to branch b to finish, those changes that were in branch a and merge into dev don't appear.

I am pretty sure I screwed up the git flow. How can branch b which is created out of dev branch those merged changes of branch a?

Comment: did you try git checkout branch b && git pull origin dev

Comment: oh let me try Govind

Comment: Worked like a charm Govind, thank you. But let me accept the below as an answer; it explained a few more things clearly, dont you agree?

Comment: Welcome @Nie Selam. I don't mind. I happy about your problem has been resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected, Git branches are a way of working on a single code base by multiple people at the same time. To do this; it uses code base state at a given time as a reference. So when you branch `b` of `dev` was at a certain that was different from the branch `a`.

Following should be something when you the branches look like when you create the new branch `B`(2)

```
     /------- A ---------
----(1)---- Dev ---(2)-----------------
                     \--------- B -----
```

Now somewhere along the line the branch `A` is merged back to `Dev`(3). So this should be what the branch should look like

```
     /------- A ----------\
----(1)---- Dev ---(2)----(3)----------------
                     \--------- B -----------
```

Now when you're on the `Dev` branch, it knows about the changes from `A`(3) since it been merged back.

But branch `B` don't know about this as it merged off from `Dev`(2) before the branch `A`(3) merged back.

To get the branch `B` inline with `Dev`, you've two options now.

1. Merged `Dev` into `B`. `git checkout b; git merged dev`
2. Rebase `Dev` on to `B`. `git checkout b; git pull --rebase origin dev`. Don't recommend this if you're a noob to git. It can sometimes go wrong in a hurry.